# My Choropleth map only shows the map, and not the colours

Tags: python, plotly

I am new to python and wanted to try using a choropleth map. I have the following code for the graph.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\lukee\Desktop\COVID Visualisation\time_series_covid_19_confirmed.csv')


#Data for number of cases for each country across the different dates
geojson = df['Country/Region']

#define the colour codes for the number of cases across the different dates
colourscale = px.colors.sequential.Plasma

#world map to show the intensity of cases in each country
fig = px.choropleth(df,
                    geojson=geojson,
                    locationmode= 'country names',
                    color = df['5/16/21'],
                    color_continuous_scale = colourscale,
                    scope='world',
                    hover_name=df["Country/Region"],
                    labels={'COVID Cases'})
fig.update(layout_coloraxis_showscale=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Please type your code in the question, not post an image. We can't try out and debug an image.

Comment: add your code as text in question,  plus your data sources if you can.  I plot choropeth for UK daily COVID data with UK geojson (using geopandas).  I do also do choropeths for 100 countries,  but use folium as base for that not plotly

Comment: Apolagies, the code has been added. The source for the data is https://www.kaggle.com/sudalairajkumar/novel-corona-virus-2019-dataset

Answer (score 0):

- solution uses sourcing open world, not kaggle
- plotting code,  there were some inconsistencies on how you requested columns in data frame.  addition of **featureidkey** parameter so dataframe and geojson join correctly

#### data sourcing

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import json, io

# source geojson for country boundaries
geosrc = pd.json_normalize(requests.get("https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/geo-countries/7/datapackage.json").json()["resources"])
fn = Path(geosrc.loc[geosrc["name"].eq("geo-countries_zip"), "path"].values[0]).name

if not Path.cwd().joinpath(fn).exists():
    r = requests.get(geosrc.loc[geosrc["name"].eq("geo-countries_zip"), "path"].values[0],stream=True,)
    with open(fn, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)

zfile = ZipFile(fn)
with zfile.open(zfile.infolist()[0]) as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)

# source COVID data
dfall = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv").text))
dfall["date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfall["date"])
dflatest = (dfall.sort_values(["iso_code", "date"]).groupby("iso_code", as_index=False).last())

colorcol = "new_cases_smoothed_per_million"
# filter out where data is no for a country or no data available for latest date or a big outlier
dflatest = dflatest.loc[
    dflatest[colorcol].gt(0).fillna(False)
    & dflatest["iso_code"].str.len().eq(3)
    & dflatest[colorcol].lt(dflatest[colorcol].quantile(0.97))
]
```

#### plotting

```
import plotly.express as px

#define the colour codes for the number of cases across the different dates
colourscale = px.colors.sequential.Plasma

#world map to show the intensity of cases in each country
fig = px.choropleth(dflatest,
                    geojson=geojson,
                    locations= 'iso_code',
                    featureidkey="properties.ISO_A3",
                    color = colorcol,
                    color_continuous_scale = colourscale,
                    scope='world',
                    hover_name="location",
                    labels={colorcol:'COVID Cases'}
                   )
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_showscale=False, margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":0,"r":0})
fig
```

#### output

[image]